# How to filter out a row in the middle of a pandas data frame by index position

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame of 20,000 observations. I want to filter out only observation 879. I tried the following:

df.iloc[-879, ]

That yielded just the column names though. How would I take out one specific column in the middle of the data frame?

The following was suggested: How to get a value from a cell of a dataframe?

It does not answer the question. It shows how to pull a value out of a cell based on filtering by column value. i need to filter by index position and only one row, in the middle of the data frame.

So I need index [0:878] and index [880:]

Comment: `df.drop(df.index[879])`?

Comment: I got `TypeError: 'RangeIndex' object is not callable`

Comment: Nope. It worked.  I used `()` instead of `[]`.  My bad. thank you!

Comment: extra `-` not needed, should just be `[879]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `np.r_`:

```
df.iloc[np.r_[:879, 880:]]
```

or `drop`:

```
df.drop(df.index[879])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Instead of 1 insert your desired index to filter out.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( {'a':[2,4,6], 'b':[7,3,5], 'c':[1,2,7] } )
row_ilocs = [ x for x in range( df.shape[1]) if x != 1 ]
df = df.iloc[ row_ilocs, :  ]
```